# builtins.ValueError: 'e' is not in list

Tags: python

```
graphics=['''------------''',                 
'''------------
|         |  ''',

'''------------
|         |         
|          O''',
'''------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / |''',
'''------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / | 
|          | ''',
'''------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         / | 
|
|            ''']

print('Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!')


while True:
    words=['table','chair','pencil','stapler','penney','computer','printer','cable','america','shelf']

    alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g,','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    number=input('Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list:') 

    if number=='':
        print('Empty input!')
        continue
    elif number in alphabet:
        print('Input must be an integer!')
        continue

    number=int(number)

    if number<0 or number>9:
        print('Index is out of range!')
        continue

    elif 0<=number<10:
        break

words2=[]
words2.extend(words[number])


print('The length of the word is: ',len(words2))


i=0
j=0
x='_'*len(words2)
blankword=[]
blankword.extend(x)

while j<6 and i!=len(words2):
    print('')

    letter=input('Please enter the letter you guess: ')

    if letter in words2:
        increment=0
        print('The letter is in the word.')
        i=i+1

        while words2.count(letter)!=blankword.count(letter):

            place=words2.index(letter,increment)
            blankword[place]=letter
            blankword2=''.join(blankword)
            i=i+1
            increment=increment+1



        if i==len(words2):
                print('You have found the mystery word. You win!')
                print('Letters matched so far:',blankword2)
                print('Goodbye!')
                break

        else:
            print('Letters matched so far: ',blankword2)
            continue

    elif letter not in words2:
        if letter not in alphabet:
            print('You need to input a single alphabetic character!')

        elif letter not in words2:
            blankword2=''.join(blankword)
            print('The letter is not in the word.')
            print('Letters matched so far: ',blankword2)
            print(graphics[j])
            j=j+1

            if j==6:
                print('Too many incorrect guesses. You lost!')
                print('The word was:',words[number])
                print('Goodbye!') 
                break
```

The result is I am getting is.

```
    Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!
Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list:4
The length of the word is:  6



   Please enter the letter you guess: p
The letter is in the word.
Letters matched so far:  p_____

Please enter the letter you guess: e
The letter is in the word.
You have found the mystery word. You win!
Letters matched so far: pe__e_
Goodbye!
```

Hi. This is a python hangman game I made but I am getting this error every time i run it. I do not know what this error means. Does anyone know what is causing this error? It works fine otherwise.
Thanks!

PS

Comment: Is that the complete traceback?

Comment: I have edited it to show you the full result

Comment: You are calling `.index()` on a list where the first argument is not a member of that list.

Comment: sorry but could you explain again.?

Comment: Documentation explicitly says it is an error if the value is not found. In that case, you need to handle the ValueError.

Comment: Look at your use of `.index()`: `place=words2.index(letter,increment)` at some point the value of `letter` is not in the `words2` list.

Comment: As per [`str.find` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.index#str.index),

*Like find(), but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.*

Comment: @DanD.but that seems to be impossible because the loop only works till a certain number is reached for a particular letter and as soon as that is reached it stops. It works for 2 letters (e and p in this case) but on the 3rd input it gives this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not the only problem but the reason why you get `ValueError` in the example you posted even though 'n' is part of 'penney' is because you never reset `increment` and it is used as the start of the search when you call `index` on the string.

Since you entered 'e' on your second try, increment will equal 3 and starting from there, it will never find 'n'.

Here's a small piece of your original code I modified to make it worked. I got rid of increment.

```
if letter in words2:

    print('The letter is in the word.')

    place = -1
    while words2.count(letter)!=blankword.count(letter):

        place=words2.index(letter, place+1)
        blankword[place]=letter
        blankword2=''.join(blankword)
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Hey I also edited my code and something even more weird happens. I put increment before the while loop. secondly, why did you put place=-1? i get everything else.

Comment: Oh nvm. you put it -1 to make it 0 in the execution. Works like a charm. ps-Why was it not working with mine? If i use what you gave me it doesn't exit the loop for some reason

Comment: It is the start of index again. I didn't test all cases but of the top of my head, if the letter you search for is at the end, it will find it multiple time since you will call index with start=0, then start=1, etc. It might lead to weird cases. With my code, the next search starts right after the letter it just found.

Comment: okk and what about it not exiting the loop when i is equalling the word length

Comment: It's because it is actually going over len because you increment i before the while loop and then every turn of the loop, remove the increment before the loop. It works on my side.